# Updating Contentful entry with a link/reference field

Tags: ruby, contentful

The Contentful documentation is pretty sparse. I want to update a field on an entry that is a Link to another entry ("Reference" is what they call it in the CMS UI).

Does anyone know what format they want this in when using the Contentful Management API?

```
type  ||= @mgmt.content_types.find(
  ENV['CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID'], 'comments'
)

entry = type.entries.create(
  title: params[:title],
  article: params[:article]
)
```

Where `:article` is the entry ID as a string. This returns:

```
undefined method `id' for "7L4IpEtsdffds8EsmoWMGIgy":String
Extracted source (around line #74):

#72         case field.type
#73         when ContentType::LINK then
*74           { sys: { type: field.type, linkType: field.link_type, id: attribute.id } } if attribute
#75         when ContentType::ARRAY then
#76           parse_fields_array(attribute)
#77         when ContentType::LOCATION then
```

I've also tried to replace `params[:article]` with `@client.entry(params[:article])` thinking they may want the whole object but it returns the same error only it sees the same argument as an empty string.

I have also tried this upon @DavidLitvak's suggestion:

```
link = Contentful::Management::Link.new({
  sys: {
    type: 'Link',
    linkType: 'Entry',
    id: params[:article]
  }
})

entry = type.entries.create(
  title: params[:title],
  article: link
)
```

And although this does not throw an error, the article field shows up without an entry while the title field is populated.

Also note that I am using the Ruby gem: `contentful-management`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to send is the `Link` for the referenced article.

You can do this like:

```
entry = type.entries.create(
  title: params[:title],
  article: Contentful::Management::Link.new({
    sys: {
      id: params[:article],
      type: 'Link',
      linkType: 'Entry'
    }
  })
)
```

You can find more information on how Links work here: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/links/

Comment: This successfully generates a link hash and passes the case this time, so no errors. But it still doesn't create a link in the CMS. The field is still empty.

Comment: Can you open a support request at https://support.contentful.com/hc/en-us. There we can better help you with your issue.

Comment: This does not work for me either. no error and the link does not show up in the cms